# Why my matTooltip shows the template as [object object]?

Tags: angular

I want to display the tooltip when hover the element. But it shows [object object]

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qf4jea?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

Html Code:

```
<button mat-raised-button
    matTooltip="Info about the action"
    aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
    Action
 </button>
 <div [matTooltip]="$any(template)" style="width:200px">
     <p>Test</p>
 </div>
 <ng-template #template>
     <div>Hello World</div>
 </ng-template>
```

TS Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';


@Component({
 selector: 'tooltip-overview-example',
 templateUrl: 'tooltip-overview-example.html',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [MatButtonModule, MatTooltipModule],
})
export class TooltipOverviewExample {}
```

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue in the question here on Stack Overflow, not just on another site. Stack Overflow questions should stand on their own and be able to be answered without visiting another site.

Comment: it seems like matTooltip only accepts strings, so you cannot get it to show an element

Comment: yes only string is supported in MatTooltip. You can create a custom tooltip with custom template if you want with the cdk, for instance: https://indepth.dev/posts/1146/tooltip-with-angular-cdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matTooltip does not support custom templates, so matTooltip has to be `string` (see API https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api), unfortunately there is no way to make it work with #template.